# Отфильтровать значения массива, содержащие одну из подстрок

Tags: php

```
$source = array("aaaaa", "bxxxb", "ccccc", "dyyyd", "eeeee");
$to_remove = array("xxx", "yyy");
$dest = somefunc($source, $to_remove);
```

нужно из первого массива убрать все элементы, содержащие одну из подстрок второго, т.е. на выходе

```
$dest = array("aaaaa", "ccccc", "eeeee");
```

сделал через **array_filter**, в callback-функции через цикл проверил через **stripos** все подстроки, но, сдаётся мне, при столь богатом наборе функций в php для работы с массивами, это вполне можно сделать без циклов?

```
<?php
  $source = array('aaaaa', 'bxxxb', 'ccccc', 'dyyyd', 'eeeee');
  $to_remove = array('xxx', 'yyy', 'ccc');
  
  $dest = array_filter($source,
                       function ($elem) use ($to_remove){
                         foreach($to_remove as $sub){
                           //echo $sub.' -> '.$elem.'?';
                           if(stripos($elem, $sub) !== false){
                            //echo ' yes'."\n";
                            return false;
                           } else {
                            //echo ' no'."\n";
                           };
                         }
                         return true;
                       }
                      );
  $dest = array_values($dest); //Переиндексация
  
  foreach($dest as $idx => $item){
    echo $idx.". ".$item."\n";
  }
?>
```

output:

```
0. aaaaa
1. eeeee
```

Comment: Боязнь циклов, она чем вызвана? Обойти массив можно только циклом, либо ты его напишешь явно, либо он где-то под капотом будет реализован.

Comment: это, в общем, не боязнь циклов, просто в образовательных целях. Что-то новое всегда интереснее узнать, чем изобретать очередное колесо

Comment: я это и имею ввиду, возможно что-то типа функции сравнения не с одной строкой, а с одной из массива уже реализована, просто мне не известна

Comment: Список функций для работы с массивами не столь богат, и вы вполне можете просмотреть его в документации самостоятельно. И убедиться, что при всем богатстве, в РНР нет функций буквально на каждый чих, и иногда код приходится писать самому.

Comment: @Ипатьев бывает напишешь реализацию на страницу, а другой человек напишет тот же функционал в одну строчку. Это иногда познавательно. Хотелось бы увидеть более компактные варианты, например

Comment: **Ну так и напишите свой код на страницу** если хотите более компактных решений

Comment: Вместо внутреннего цикла можно использовать preg_match c шаблоном, полученным из `implode("|", array_map('preg_quote', $to_remove));` и соответсевующими флагами.

Comment: В целом же, как можно увидеть, стремление "сделать короче" часто играет с нами злую шутку, заставляя писать код, который оказывается *сложнее* чем [банальный цикл](https://3v4l.org/UCa34) :)

Comment: Хотя, конечно, при желании, можно и "без циклов" уложиться в [то же самое количество строк](https://3v4l.org/8Zvp7) :)